# Compiling c++ program with multiple files

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a c++ program with multiple files!

### mainfile.cc

```
#include<iostream>
#include "funcfile.hh"
int main()
{
init();
}
```

### funcfile.hh

```
#include<iostream>
void init();
```

### funcfile.cc

```
#include<iostream>
#include "funcfile.hh"
using namespace std;

void init()
{
cout<<"hi"<<endl;
}
```

I am creating the binary as below:

```
> CC funcfile.cc mainfile.cc -o output
funcfile.cc:
mainfile.cc:
ld: warning: symbol .dynsym[19] has invalid section index; ignored:
        (file /usr/local/opt/SunWorkShop/sws_5.0/SUNWspro/lib/libm.so value=19);
```

And when i execute the output:

```
> ./output
hi
>
```

But my concern here is should I care about the message during the compilation:

```
ld: warning: symbol .dynsym[19] has invalid section index; ignored:
            (file /usr/local/opt/SunWorkShop/sws_5.0/SUNWspro/lib/libm.so value=19);
```

CC version is :

```
> CC -V
CC: WorkShop Compilers 5.0 98/12/15 C++ 5.0
```

Comment: you can see the compiler version i am using and its a c++ compiler.I am removing the tag C

Comment: But your question talks about compiling a C program. OK, I fixed it.

Comment: Well i have rephrased it. But the context here is compilation warning.

Comment: can you run elfdump on it: $ elfdump -sN.dynsym libfoo.so | grep array | sort -k 2,2  per here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-0690/6n33n7f5e/index.html

Comment: You should put include guards in `funcfile.hh`.

Comment: Try using g++ compiler !

Comment: even after adding header guards, the warning is coming.

Comment: The header guards doesn't matter since it's not actually a compiler error, it's a *linker* error. But it's still good practice to have them. The problem may be that you're using a *very* old compiler which might not work very well if your version of Solaris is too new.

Comment: it says it's the math library's fault...

Answer (score 1):

You are using a compiler that is almost 15 years old. The ELF format has evolved a little bit during that time, it seems that your compiler does not recognize some of the newer special section indexes (see e.g. [here, table 7-4](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/819-0690/chapter6-93046.html)). This warning is not something to worry about, but I'd suggest to use a newer compiler, if possible.